# Collada to URDF Conversion

Tags: collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I want to load a collada file with kinematics and joints of a robot into V-Rep, which only supports URDF for kinematics.
I found the collada_parser which seems to be able to convert a collada file to URDF, but I have no idea how to convert or use it. Is it even possible to export the kinematics this way?

Thanks for your help,
Daniel

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163136/collada-to-urdf-conversion/) by [L-Dani](https://answers.ros.org/users/17821/l-dani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

try:
rosrun collada_urdf collada_to_urdf *.dae *.urdf

---

Originally posted by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) with karma: 131 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [L-Dani](https://answers.ros.org/users/17821/l-dani/) on 2014-05-09**:
hey, thank you for the answer, but I want to convert the other way round: collada to urdf.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2014-05-09**:
What's wrong with @Bastbeat's answer? Anyway `collada_urdf` package provides conversion in both ways. http://wiki.ros.org/collada_urdf#collada_to_urdf_command-line_tool

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2018-09-24**:
when i try this i get an error :

$ rosrun collada_urdf collada_to_urdf *.dae *.urdf
;; Input file is: *.dae
Error:   Error document empty.
at line 72 in /build/urdfdom-UJ3kd6/urdfdom-0.4.1/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
ERROR: Model Parsing the xml failed
I am unable to locate this file anywhere.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2018-09-24**:
@curi_ROS Please open a new question thread instead of asking a question in a comment section. That's not how this forum works and to the worst your question won't get attention it might need.